# Components written against log4j1 are not logging after log4j2 upgrade

Tags: java, tomcat, log4j, log4j2

I've been banging my head over this one for a few days and can't get it figured out. Log4j2 is backwards compatible if you add the log4j1 compatibility library.

My web-inf\lib has:

- slf-api
- log4j-1.2-api (backwards compat. library)
- log4j-api (log4j2)
- log4j-core (log4j2)
- log4j-web (auto-wiring for web applications)

My web.xml has:

```
<!-- log4j2 auto-wiring -->
<context-param>
    <param-name>log4jConfiguration</param-name>
    <param-value>file:///${catalina.base}/conf/log4j2.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
```

My [tomcat]/conf/log4j2.xml is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="debug">
    <Appenders>
        <!-- Appends to CONSOLE -->
        <Console name="consoleAppender" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <ThresholdFilter level="DEBUG" onMatch="ACCEPT" onMismatch="DENY" />
            <PatternLayout pattern="%5p (%F:%L) - %m%n" />
        </Console>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Logger name="com.mycompany.componentA" level="WARN" />
        <Logger name="com.mycompany.componentA.QueryLogger" level="DEBUG" />
        <Logger name="com.mycompany.mycode" level="DEBUG" />
        <Root level="WARN">
            <AppenderRef ref="consoleAppender" />
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

I have upgraded code under my control (com.mycompany.mycode) to log4j2 APIs and they work/log flawlessly. Code that is not under my control but was written against log4j1 (com.mycompany.componentA) just simply fails to log at all. No errors, no debugs, nothing.

Something interesting though... when I start the application I get a log4j1 warning about incorrect configurations when the application starts. This also stumps me because there are no log4j1 libraries (except the compatibility API) in the WAR. Warning is:

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (com.mycompany.componentB) 
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly. 
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EDIT: I (finally) figured out what's going on. One of my dependencies did a horribly bad thing and BUNDLED the log4j1 classes into it's final jar. So there are no log4j1 jars on the classpath, but there are log4j1 CLASSES on the classpath.

The only way I was able to get this working was to:

1. Create BOTH a log4j1 and log4j2 XML configuration files (even though the log4j2 configuration contained all the loggers I wanted)
2. Let Log4j2 auto-wire itself via the 'log4j-web' artifact + 'log4jConfiguration' web.xml parameter
3. Manually wire log4j1 by calling the deprecated Log4jConfigurer.initLogging(...) API on server startup

This is probably horribly incorrect, but as indicated above, it was the only way I got it working after weeks of fooling around.

My understanding of the lo4j1 bridge is that wiring up log4j2 and including the bridge is all that should be required (e.g. no need to manually wire log4j1). In practice, that does not seem to be occurring.

Comment: That confirms Ralph's and my hypothesis that the log4j1 jar is still in the classpath.

Comment: Updated my answer with another way to find the Log4j 1 jar location.

Comment: No, it doesn't confirm that. All log4j1 API calls are bridged to log4j2 calls. So all it really confirms is that you don't have any more of an idea about what's wrong than I do.

Comment: `Log4jConfigurer` only exists in the Log4j 1 jar. It is not included in the log4j-1.2-api-2.x bridge. Log4j 2 ignores log4j1 configurations. If you need both a Log4j 1 configuration and a Log4j 2 configuration file for your app to work then you have Log4j 1 in the classpath.

Comment: Unfortunately incorrect again. It's part of the Spring Framework. http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/util/Log4jConfigurer.html

Comment: Have you tried the `AppenderSkeleton.class.getResource("/" + AppenderSkeleton.class.getName().replace('.', '/') + ".class")` to find the location? (I think it needs a leading slash but try without if it returns `null`.)

Comment: I stand corrected on Log4jConfigurer. Still can't think of any other explanation.

Comment: AppenderSkeleton is not in the bridge jar, so the AppenderSkeleton.class.getResource() idea should work.

Answer (score 1):

That error message means you still have the log4j-1.x jar in your application. Look for it in your WEB-INF/lib and remove it and then it should work.

Comment: Per summary, I do not have any log4j1 libraries in webinf

Comment: The message you are seeing comes from log4j 1.x's initialization code, so it has to be in the classparh somewhere. Keep looking until you find it.

Answer (score 1):

If not in WEB-INF/lib, then perhaps in your web container (Tomcat?) shared lib folder? Ralph is right that this error message is generated by Log4j-1.2, so it is on the classpath somewhere... Try printing the value of System property `java.class.path` if necessary.

---

Update: another way to find the location of the Log4j1 jar is by printing the value of `org.apache.log4j.AppenderSkeleton.class.getResource("/org/apache/log4j/AppenderSkeleton.class")` from your application.

(I originally suggested `Category` but this also exists in the Log4j 1 bridge, so `AppenderSkeleton` is better.)

Comment: Were our answers useful?